# ACPI and AMD GPU errors while attempting to install Ubuntu or Mint

Tags: bios, acpi, amd, watchdog, iommu

I have been trying to dual boot windows and Linux. I am facing similar problems for both Ubuntu and Mint. The attached image shows the errors that i am getting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Either find a distro with a fresh kernel (e.g. Fedora 34 beta) or try booting with either of these arguments: `iommu=soft` or `pci=noats`

More info here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1015